# Merge [template-deduction] and [argument-deduction]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

There are 334 questions tagged [template-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-deduction), all of which are about C++. There are 71 questions tagged [argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argument-deduction) tag, all of which are about C++ [save one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961504/unexpected-behavior-method-overload-with-params-array), where the presence of the tag appears to be a mistake.

These tags seem to have the same intended meaning. A possible name for the merged tag is [template-argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-argument-deduction) (as it is called in the C++ standard).

Comment: For those who are not familiar with C++: template arguments are the only arguments that can be deduced in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done since, as [L. F. said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387568/merge-template-deduction-and-argument-deduction#comment714760_387568), template arguments are the only arguments which can be deduced.

I liked your proposed name, so [template-argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-argument-deduction) is now the "master" tag. After verifying that all questions [argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argument-deduction) and [template-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-deduction) were both merged into it. I also created synonym mappings.

There was one straggler question tagged [argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argument-deduction) that was not about C++. I dropped the tag off of that C# question before merging.

While I was doing this, I also noticed a [class-template-argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-template-argument-deduction) tag with 2 questions, so I merged that one into the master [template-argument-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-argument-deduction) tag, as well.